# why android splash screen is not showing in landscape orientation of kitkat & older devices?

Tags: java, android, splash-screen, android-4.4-kitkat, landscape

I have added splash screen in my android app (which has android API level 14-26 target support) as follows:

In my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

In styles.xml, the SplashTheme is defined as:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_graphic</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

My splash_graphic.xml as follows:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/my_logo" android:tileMode="disabled" android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And my Splash Activity as:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, ActivationActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

**My strange problem is**:
The splash screen works OK in both Landscape and Portrait screen orientations on Lollipop and newer devices but it works only in Portrait screen orientation on Kitkat and pre-kitkat devices. How can I get it work for Landscape orientation too on kitkat and pre-kitkat devices too?

Comment: What is the problem exactly ? it doesnt switch to lanscape orientation ? do you want it to switch on device rotation or do you want it to always be landscape?

Comment: did you try adding `screenOrientation` attribute in splash activity tag in ur manifest?

Comment: I want the splash screen shown in what ever screen orientation I launch the app, it must be shown. For eg. If I open the app in Landscape orientation, the splash screen must be shown in landscape orientation, but the problem in only kitkat and older devices is: it does not show up at all if I launch the app in landscape screen orientation. FYI, I had tried by adding screenOrientation attribute earlier, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so many hours of searching, I finally came to a solution for my strange problem, which is not a coding solution. This may sound little awkward, however,
I want to share it just because it worked for me and I think it can be helpful for other people. So, here is my workaround:

**Caused By:**

> This problem was being caused by the default **home launcher app** ,which manages apps showcasing in Landscape and Portrait screen orientation of devices [I observed the problem on 1. Huawei MediaPad T1 7.0
>   Tablet 2. Lenovo a-319 Rockstar and 3.Samsung Galaxy S Duos 7562 ].
>   But I did not observe any problem on any devices[Splash-screen worked
>   on any screen orientations on 1. Samsung Galaxy J Max SM-T285YD Tab
>   2.Samsung J 7 Prime phone] that had Lollipop or newer android OSes.

**The Solution:**

> So, I changed the default **home launcher app** on devices which had
>   problem. **EMUI launcher** of Huawei MediaPad tab and **Fly launcher**
>   of Lenovo a-319[I had rooted this device, so launcher is different than
>   other Lenovo phones] were replaced with **[Google Now Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher&hl=en)**
>   from google play, which now is not officially supported by google. As
>   Samsung S Duos 7562 did not support Google Now Launcher, its **TouchWiz
>   launcher** was replaced with **[Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en)** . After default home
>   launcher app replacement, now, the problem is solved on all target
>   devices.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use in java class

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

Comment: It did not help at all. Has anybody solved this problem other way?